# Integral question of Dirac's Delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I came across this exercise in a book that I was reading, it says:

What value would you assign to $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta(x))^2dx$$ ?

My attempt at a solution was to think of as so:

This integral is the same as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\delta(x)dx$, and here I used the identity that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)f(x)dx = f(0)$.

So, I allowed that $f(x) = \delta(x)$, which then yields $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta(x))^2dx = \delta(0)=\infty$$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The product of distributions isn't really well defined, but your argument is okay.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere
for more information.

Comment: Interesting. At first glance I honestly didn't think it would make any difference and would just still be 1.